#  web service to deserilize JSON http request?  and pass to stored Procedure to retrieve data from SQL server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, web-services, json, rest

I'm a newbie to VB.net. Right now I have a task to create a web service to receive client-side app's http request(with **rpc={json data}** in the end), deserilize it and put he parameter in stored Procedure in order to retrieve data from sql server.

The procedure query and client-side's app are already there and the return data to client-side app is JSON too.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please give me some suggestion or idea.

Comment: rpc={ "method": "login", "params":  ["username",  "pwd"], "id": null} via WS to EXEC dbo.procAppLogin 'username', 'pwd', '1.1.1.1', 'Application', 'Version', 1024, 768

Answer (score 0):

You can use dll like newtonsoft.dll for handling json data
In asp.net also you can handle json data using following namespace.

```
  System.Web.Script.Serialization 


Dim jsn As JavaScriptSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer() // Define JavaScriptSerializer 
// data is object which contains json data
Dim objjsn As Object = jsn.DeserializeObject(data) //Deserialize json

Dim args As Array = objjsn("users") // access json data
```

Comment: in your case  Dim rpc As Object = "{""method"": ""login"", ""params"": [""username"", ""pwd""], ""id"": null}"
        Dim jsn As JavaScriptSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()
        Dim objjsn As Object = jsn.DeserializeObject(rpc)
        Dim args As Array = objjsn("params")

Comment: https://<webserivce>/rpc={json data}   if http request is like this, then what? and how to extract parameters from json and put in stored procedure?